# How to use text over image with click event in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to qt. Actually I'm having image for my project. I need to display the image and also the text over the image with click event. I've tried using `QLabel` to display the image as well as text but it doesn't support click events. Here's what I've tried:

```
mylabel->setText("Wh");
mylabel->setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel {background-image: url(\"sample.bmp\");color : blue;}"));
mylabel->setGeometry(10,10,78,78);
mylabel->setFont(QFont("Arial", 12));
mylabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

I've tried mouse events, it also works fine but I don't know how to compare the event position with the label positions (xpos,ypos). Also if I change the position of label (setGeometry) during run time it is even more difficult to compare the label position (xpos,ypos). I used my mouseRelease event like,

```
void SampleProject::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    int Xpos=event->x();
    int Ypos=event->y();
    QString s = QString::number(Xpos);
    QString t = QString::number(Ypos);

    QMessageBox::question(this, s, t, QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

    emit clicked(event->pos());
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a QLabel? If you are looking for just a clickable image; you can style the QPushButton similar to QLabel: `ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet(QString("QPushButton {background-image: url(\"img.jpg\"); border-style: none}"));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you're asking right, but if I did, you should subclass `QLabel` and use it's `mouseReleaseEvent` instead of a global one. You can also make your own signals for mouse clicks, if you want to:

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override
    {
        setText("I have been clicked!");//you can change the text here directly on click
        QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(ev);
        emit clicked();//or you can emit a signal, and use it elsewhere
    }
signals:
    void clicked();
};
```

If you emit the `clicked` signal, you can easilly get the label that emmited it in the slot:

```
class LabelClickHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void onLabelClicked()
    {
        MyLabel * label = dynamic_cast<MyLabel*>(sender());
        //do some stuff with the label
    }
};
```